# Run motd.dynamic only with interactive (terminal and SSH) login

Tags: login, sftp

I have successfully used motd.dynamic to create my own dynamic MOTD. However, my MOTD contains information considered useful to logged-in terminal/SSH users. As SFTP cannot display this information, but the motd.dynamic still runs the necessary actions to collect this data from the system, thus slowing the SFTP (as well as other) logins somewhat. I wish to disable running motd.dynamic when the user is not logging in from an interactive session (terminal or with SSH). How can I achieve this?

I understand that the variable $- contains interactive login information ("i"), but this is not set until motd.dynamic is finished, so I cannot use the motd.dynamic script itself to continue or not running based on "i" being present or not with $-.

Comment: what err u say?